# How do we offer tahiyatul wudu prayers, and do we perform it even in the prohibited times?

Tags: salat, wudu, nafl

when can we pray nafal after wadu and how to pray it . Specifically i want to know can we pray wadu nafal on fajr and asar time as it is prohibited to pray nafal on fajr and asar time. And also is it necessary to pray tahiyatul wudu nafal while the body is  still wet after wadu??

Answer (score 2):

It is recommended to perform two rakah supererogatory salah after doing wudu, based on the hadith:

> ما من مسلم يتوضأ فيحسن وضوءه ثم يقوم فيصلي ركعتين مقبل عليهما بقلبه ووجهه إلا وجبت له الجنة ‏
>
> There is no Muslim who performs wudu' and does it well,
> then stands and prays two Rak'ah in which his heart is focused as
> he faces the Qiblah, but Paradise will be due to him.
>
> <sup>— [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:234a)</sup>

As for the prohibited or disliked times, then there is difference among the madhabs. According to the Hanafis and Hanbalis a person should **not** perform this prayer in those times, as obeying the prohibition is more important than performing a supererogatory act.

While the Shafi'is say that the prohibition does not apply to this prayer as according to them the prohibition only applies to those supererogatory prayers which do not have a cause.

**Ref:** [Mawsoo’ah al-Fiqhiyyah 43/379](https://archive.org/details/FPmfkmfk/mfk43/page/n377/mode/2up?view=theater)